# "Empty encoded password" calling for token without client secret

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have client defined to use password grant without client secret, but when I'm calling for token It's not working and I'm getting a warning `BCryptPasswordEncoder : Empty encoded password`. Spring Security allows using clients without a secret, in `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` I fount that `PasswordEncoder` should match if encoded password is empty, but it never gets to that point, `BasicAuthenticationFilter` because stops it with different password encoder.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final CustomerLoginService userDetailsService;

    private final OAuthClientDetailsService oAuthClientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthServerConfig(@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                            CustomerLoginService userDetailsService,
                            OAuthClientDetailsService oAuthClientDetailsService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.oAuthClientDetailsService = oAuthClientDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(oAuthClientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(new InMemoryTokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your authorization server configuration. BTW: A warning doesn't mean your code is not working.